# No sound or vibration in Android push notifications in Expo Client

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo

hi i'm new to react native I am just testing around with the push notification on android. but there is no vibration or sound when i test on my android device via expo client.

However when i open the app on my android devices via expo client, the push notification does show up, but there was no sound no vibration even though i set those to true already.

i want to make a notification than notify the user every day at 8 AM even if the app is closed can i make it ??

```
async componentWillMount() {
    let result = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    if (result.status === "granted" && this.state.switchStatus) {
      console.log("Notification permissions granted.");
      this.setNotifications();
    } else {
      console.log("No Permission", Constants.lisDevice);
    }

    this.listenForNotifications();
  }
  getNotification(date) {
    const localNotification = {
      title: `Notification at ${date.toLocaleTimeString()}`,
      body: "N'oubliez pas de prendre tes medicament",
      ios: {

        sound: true 
      },

      android: {
        sound: true, 
        priority: "max", 
        sticky: false, 
        vibrate: true 
      }
    };
    return localNotification;
  }
  setNotifications() {
    Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync();

    for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      //Maximum schedule notification is 64 on ios.
      let t = new Date();
      if (i === 0) {
        t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 1);
      } else {
        t.setMinutes(t.getMinutes() + 1 + i * 1);
      }
      const schedulingOptions = {
        time: t 
      };
      Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(
        this.getNotification(t),
        schedulingOptions
      );
    }
  }
  listenForNotifications = () => {
    Notifications.addListener(notification => {
      console.log("received notification", notification);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found a solution for the sound and vibration it's not the best as i said i'm new to RN but still it works ( i used this: "create Channel Android Async" )

```
async componentWillMount() {
    let result = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    if (result.status === "granted" && this.state.switchStatus) {
    // i add this :
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  Notifications.createChannelAndroidAsync('chat-messages', {
    name: 'Chat messages',
    sound: true,
    vibrate: true,
  });
}
      console.log("Notification permissions granted.");

      this.setNotifications();
    } else {
      console.log("No Permission", Constants.lisDevice);
    }

    this.listenForNotifications(); 
  }

  getNotification(date) {

    const localNotification = {
      title: `Notification at ${date.toLocaleTimeString()}`,
      body: "N'oubliez pas de prendre tes medicament", 
      ios: {

        sound: true 
      },

      android: {
       "channelId": "chat-messages" //and this
            }
    };
    return localNotification;
  }
  setNotifications() {
    Notifications.cancelAllScheduledNotificationsAsync();

    for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      //Maximum schedule notification is 64 on ios.
      let t = new Date();
      if (i === 0) {
        t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 1);
      } else {
        t.setMinutes(t.getMinutes() + 1 + i * 1); // 15 Minutes
      }
      const schedulingOptions = {
        time: t 
      };
      Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(
        this.getNotification(t),
        schedulingOptions
      );
    }
  }
  listenForNotifications = () => {
    Notifications.addListener(notification => {
      console.log("received notification", notification);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Your code works great for me but only the first one or two notifications come through and then it stops.  Any idea why this may be?

Comment: Thanks!  that code is just for the problem of not receiving notifications. so now you have to schedulnotifications  as meet your needs and it will works. sorry for the late reply ^^

Answer (score 1):

In my case i allowed notification sound in (settings -> notifications -> your-app-name -> sound -> allow ), And it worked fine afterwords

Answer (score 0):

In your app.json file, add

`android:{useNextNotificationApi:true }`

Comment: welcome. Can you add a bit more of context on how this helps and some reference information. This can help the value for future searches to understand the solution purposed.

Answer (score 0):

My issue on no vibration on Android (ok in IOS) was I had i like this:

```
  Vibration.vibrate([100]);
```

Where it needed to be

```
  Vibration.vibrate();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using just a single Notification channel, and trying to use the `sound` argument when i created the local notification. This doesn't work on newer Android versions (it works fine on iOS)...

You need to create new channels for each different custom sound:

```
await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('general', {
        name: 'General Notifications',
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        sound: 'general.wav',
      });
      await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('daily_affirmation', {
        name: 'Daily Affirmation',
        importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
        vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        sound: 'affirmation_notification.wav',
      });
```

**(note that for some reason, I couldn't use a custom notification sound on the 'default' channel).**

And then you can use something like this, and the custom notification sound works:

```
const result = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
          identifier: 'daily_affirmation_1',
          content: {
            title: 'test', 
            body: 'test body',
            data: { type, url },
            sound, // this is iOS only. Android uses the channelId to dictate the custom sound
            vibrate: [],
            priority: AndroidNotificationPriority.MAX,
          },
          trigger: {
            date,
            'daily_affirmation', // this is Android only, and allows us to use a custom sound
          },
        });
```

In you app.json:

```
"expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./assets/rt-android-notification-icon.png",
          "color": "#ffffff",
          "sounds": ["assets/audio/affirmation_notification.wav", "assets/audio/general.wav"]
        }
```

For remote push notifications, you may also need to add this to your app.json:

```
android:{useNextNotificationApi:true }
```